# How to add link mark as read notification rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

a have notification system in my app its look like this:
app/views/static_pages/notification.html.erb

```
<div class="notification">
    <h4>notification</h4>
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <ul>
        <li>
    <%= render "activities/#{activity.trackable_type.underscore}/#{activity.action}", activity: activity %>
        </li>
    </ul>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "mark all as read"%>
</div>
```

and have code in application controller

```
def activity
    if signed_in?
      @activities = current_user.activities.includes(:author, :trackable).where(read:false).order(created_at: :desc)  
    end
  end
```

db activity have "read" boolean column, i need update this column to true when user click to link `<%= link_to "mark all as read"%>`in notification view but i doesnt know how to do this? please help! Thank's

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do? is it a method that makes all as read? or is it the style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create new controller method, read_all, with contents:

   ```
   def read_all
     current_user.activities.where(read: false).update_all(read: true)
   end
   ```
2. Set up a route. If you have set up read_all method inside ActivitiesController, do:

   ```
   resources :activities do
     post :read_all, on: :collection
   end
   ```
3. Make a link:

   ```
   <%= button_to "Read all", read_all_activities_path, method: :post %>
   ```